# How to write a DMQL query that searches a numeric number with in a given list?

Tags: rets, dmql

I am trying to connect to a Real Estate Transaction Standards (RETS) server to pull listing where `Matrix_Unique_Id` is in a list of `bigint` values.

My DMQL query IN-clause looks something like this

```
(Matrix_Unique_Id=|123456789456,845686745,845156413,8654543354)
```

However, that is giving me the following error

> DMQL: Invalid BigInt criteria for field 'Matrix_Unique_ID'string

If I use the same syntax to search for a string in a list it works fine for example

```
(Status=|Active,Pending,Expired)
```

How can I search the listing where Matrix_Unique_Id in a long list of values?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be that IN Syntax works only for string types.

To get the `bigint` working, I had to do the following nasty syntax

```
(Matrix_Unique_Id=123456789456)|(Matrix_Unique_Id=845686745)|(Matrix_Unique_Id=845156413)|(Matrix_Unique_Id=8654543354)
```

The above gave me the intended result. However, since this makes the request URI much lengthier, I had to submit multiple requests to avoid HTTP error code `404` or `414`.

Answer (score 2):

There is difference between DMQL query IN-clause for normal field and lookup field in RETS server.

In your first example you gave the query with **pipe symbol "|"**. But then it will work for lookup values like "Status", "City", "County" etc.

You should try like this for Matrix_Unique_Id(normal field),

```
(Matrix_Unique_Id=123456789456,845686745,845156413,8654543354)
```

The answer you have written also correct, but then its lengthy and useful only for multiple fields in query.

> Note: There is no difference for either bigint or string while
>   querying.